# Redis.conf for slave with sentinel

Tags: redis, persistence, failover

Should I use exact mirror of `redis.conf` on slave, if it would be promoted as master when failover activates.

For example should I `appendonly yes` to slave ?

Answer (score -1):

The slaves configuration are different than the master one, so you will need to have 1 config file per server, plus one sentinel config file. Here you have a nice tutorial to make it work (basically) https://seanmcgary.com/posts/how-to-build-a-fault-tolerant-redis-cluster-with-sentinel

Comment: first of all, I'm not using cluster. Second one, he is not telling about different configs like `appendonly` at all. Or maybe I miss something, but he is not using redis-cluster, but telling about it. `cluster-enable` ?